# Creating sniffer for OpenThread leads to error

Tags: python, wireshark, packet-sniffers, nrf52, openthread

I'm trying to build a sniffer for an OpenThread network using this [tutorial](https://openthread.io/guides/pyspinel/sniffer).
I built the `openthread/ot-nrf528xx` binaries using the `USB_trans`-Flag, flashed the `ot-rcp.hex`-File onto a Adafruit Feather nrf52840 and disabled the MSD. After that I created a small OpenThread network with only one router and one child (Also on  Adafruit Feather nrf52840 devices).

My problem now is when I try to run the `sniffer.py` with following command: `sudo python3 sniffer.py -c 15 -u /dev/ttyACM0 --crc --no-reset --rssi | wireshark -k -i -`  (with -c 15 being the channel I use in the OpenThread network and -u /dev/ttyACM0 being the USB-Port where the sniffer is connected.), I get the following log output and error message:

```
Initializing sniffer...

CB_Unknown (3): 
 ** (wireshark:11740) 12:27:54.470908 [Capture MESSAGE] -- Capture Start ...

CB_Unknown (3): 
ERROR: failed to initialize sniffer
 ** (wireshark:11740) 12:27:57.356867 [Capture MESSAGE] -- Error message from child: "Data written to the pipe is neither in a supported pcap format nor in pcapng format.", "Please report this to the developers of the program writing to the pipe."
```

Wireshark is opened, but displays the same error message.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Did I miss a step or do I maybe have to set something in wireshark?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

Thanks for any help,

Emily.